# \input{\<variable>} yields "Undefined Control Sequence"

Tags: document-classes, input, arguments, parameters, variable

I am creating a class that I want to use for creating my own worksheets. As such, I want each course that I teach to have its own information file, stored in the file , which, in the assignment, I can access by using a command such as `\course{\<course-number-term>}`.

Thus, in my class preamble file, I have the following code for the course:

```
\newcommand*{\course}[1]{\gdef\@course{#1}}
\input{\@course}
```

I know that the first line works for other text related things I am doing, and that the second line works for other static files in the same folder as my `<course-number-term>.tex` file, so each of these commands works independently, but not together, since I get the error

```
! undefined control sequence. 
\@course -> \course

l.42 \input{\@course}
```

Is there a way to pass a variable into the `\input` command, or am I doomed to a lack of flexibility?

——————EDIT——————

Thank you everyone for the comments and solutions. I should have mentioned, I'm mostly using the information from the course tex file INSIDE the preamble—so, doing anything that inputs it after the `\begin{document}` doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Between the `\newcommand{\course}` and `\input{\@course}` you need to use `\course{whatever}` to set some value to `\@course`, otherwise it will be undefined, raising the error you see

Comment: Are you using a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)?

Comment: or `\expandafter\gdef\csname @course\endcsname...`

Comment: Assuming that you are using \course{whatever} in the preamble, you could put `\AtBeginDocument{\input{\@course}}` in your cls.

Comment: you have provided no test file and the error shows `\@course -> \course` so `\@course` defined to expand to `\course` which does not match the code that you show. the error is unrelated to `\input`. Please edit the question to provide a test that people can run to debug the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have also thought of another solution that actually sounds better for your use case. It being very different from my first answer I have made a second answer.

This seems like something you could accomplish best by defining the courses you teach as class options. You can actually define a bunch of things like this and have them all change at the same time.

mycourses.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycourses}[Sep 29, 2019 short description]

\newcommand{\mycourses@course}{}%
\newcommand{\mycourses@timeslot}{}%
\newcommand{\mycourses@day}{}%

\DeclareOption{ee433}{
    \renewcommand\mycourses@course{ee433}
    \renewcommand\mycourses@timeslot{11:00am}
    \renewcommand\mycourses@day{T Th}
}

\DeclareOption{me390}{
    \renewcommand\mycourses@course{me390}
    \renewcommand\mycourses@timeslot{2:00pm}
    \renewcommand\mycourses@day{M W F}
}

\DeclareOption{stats666}{
    \renewcommand\mycourses@course{stats666}
    \renewcommand\mycourses@timeslot{6:00am}
    \renewcommand\mycourses@day{S Su}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[letterpaper,11pt]{report}

\newcommand{\course}{\mycourses@course}%
\newcommand{\timeslot}{\mycourses@timeslot}%
\newcommand{\theday}{\mycourses@day}%

\endinput
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[stats666]{mycourses}

\begin{document}

    \course{} is taught at \timeslot{} on \theday{}

\end{document}
```

Infact with this meathod, since by the time you have entered in the class option the document knows which one you are going to use, it could actually work to use a variable input command in the .cls file like this.

```
\DeclareOption{ee433}{
    \input{ee433}
}
```

Comment: This allows me to put the stuff I'm including inside the preamble of the class, which is exactly what I want to do. Ideally, I'd like to never have to edit the class file again, so this doesn't provide this flexibility, but it does help out in the meantime. Thank you!

Comment: If this is the case, that you never want to edit the .cls ever again because you want it to be modularized, I dont see the point in doing any of this `\newcommand` work. Just use the `\input{myclassfilename}` in your preamble (not in the .cls) and be done with it. You dont need to define any class options this way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok one more shot. Here is a solution using a combination of the tricks demonstrated in my prior two answers. Since they are complete as they are I don't want to change them for further readers.

We will define three files: `mycource.cls`, `main.tex`, and `stats666.tex`

mycource.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycourses}[Sep 30, 2019 short description]

\LoadClass[letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}


% \makeatletter
\newcommand{\coursename}[1]{\gdef\mycourses@coursename{#1}}%
\newcommand{\coursetime}[1]{\gdef\mycourses@coursetime{#1}}%
\newcommand{\getcoursevalue}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{mycourses@#1}%
    {\PackageError{mycourses}{Variable '#1' undefined.}{}}%
    {\csname mycourses@#1\endcsname}}
% \makeatother

\newcommand{\setclass}[1]{\coursename{#1}\include{\getcoursevalue{coursename}}}%here is where your magic happens

\endinput
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mycourses}

\setclass{stats666}%there is no way of getting around having this here

\begin{document}

\getcoursevalue{coursename} works.

\getcoursevalue{coursetime} works too.

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

stats666.tex

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\coursetime{6:00 AM, Saturday and Sunday}
```

This demonstrates how you can add preamble material inside the `classfilename.tex` as well as reference common commands setup inside your `mycourses.cls`.

You could even set up private course specific commands now in each `classfilename.tex`.

Comment: So I haven’t tried this out, but I think you’ve got something here. Thank you so much for your help! I found a workaround that works for me, and for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question, but If I have it right you are not trying to use `\input` to add more preamble? I think this is more of what you were asking for?

Here is an example of what I think you are trying to do?

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newcommand{\course}[1]{\gdef\@course{#1}}%you make new commands in your preamble (everything after \documentclass{myclass} and before your \begin{document} 


\begin{document}
    Hello I am Mr Soandso

    \course{ee433}%Here you can call the command to store ee433 to the macro \@course

    Some more friendly words.

    \input{\@course}%Here you can reference \@course to input a like named file.

    Then you can still use the name \@course any time you would like!

\end{document}
```

ee433.tex

```
Welcome to EE433
```

It will print:
[image]

EDIT----------------------------------------------------

There is something wrong with this code that I am trying to figure out. While it does work as exactly provided, for some reason if you attempt to create a second `\newcommand{\varone}[1]{\gdef\@varone{#1}}` with different names then call it the program will not compile. Im sure it has something to do with the `@` character as removing it fixes the issue.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newcommand{\course}[1]{\gdef\mycourse{#1}}%
\newcommand{\anothercommand}[1]{\gdef\myanothercourse{#1}}%

\begin{document}

\course{ee433}
\anothercommand{stats666}

\mycourse{} works and so does \myanothercourse{}.

\end{document}
```

EDIT---------------------------------------------
If you put `makeatletter` in the correct spot right above the command, it fixes the problem. However this produces some really bad spacing problems. With the help of @PhelypeOleinik  this new solution works best. It is a very elegant modification which keep keeping track of variable names nice and clean.
main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coursename}[1]{\gdef\mycourses@coursename{#1}}%
\newcommand{\coursetime}[1]{\gdef\mycourses@coursetime{#1}}%
\newcommand{\getcoursevalue}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{mycourses@#1}%
    {\PackageError{mycourses}{Variable '#1' undefined.}{}}%
    {\csname mycourses@#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\coursename{stats666}

\coursetime{6:00 AM, Saturday and Sunday}

\getcoursevalue{coursename} works.

\getcoursevalue{coursetime} works too.

\getcoursevalue{undefined} does not work.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `@` is a special character that has to be handled carefully.  Take a look at Werner's link in the second comment to the original question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to use the information that I get from inputting the course information inside the preamble itself (see my edits), which means this solution doesn't work for me. Thanks for the help though!